# Cannot see or access Group Policy Preferences

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to follow this [procedure](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc753092.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to add a registry key to all my domains computer. The thing is that I don't see anything under:

- Computer Configuration

  - Preferences

    - Windows Settings

It does that no matter what policy I choose.
I am using Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: To be clear, you've expanded Windows Settings, right? And you're using the GPMC on your DC or from a management workstation that has RSAT installed? Can you post s screenshot showing the relevant section?

Comment: Yes I have expanded Windows settings in GPMC on my DC. Working on that screenshot.